# input transformation for polynomial regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression

First I apologize if the question is not very clear as I'm new to this field. I'm doing a university project to create polynomial regression in python without any kind of libraries. In our class the professor told us you have to transform the values of higher dimension if you want to change a polynomial regression problem into a linear one. for example :

[image]

so at first I generate a description file which in each line has the elements to be chosen and last number is parameter to use. and then we have the input variables. All of this is clear to me. but I don't understand how to use the description with my transformed input (out.txt) numbers.

I would be really thankful if somebody could make it more clear to me :)